# SERIALIZABLE transaction information leak via serial

Tags: postgresql, concurrency, sequence, isolation-level

I'm trying to implement a deterministic configuration for database sessions, and one problem seems to be with sequences. The following example demonstrates:

```
CREATE TABLE foo (id serial, n integer);

-- connection 1
BEGIN TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE ;

-- connection 2
BEGIN TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE ;
insert into foo (n) values (1),(2),(3);

-- connection 1
select nextval('fun_id_seq') - (select count(*) from fun) as leak;

leak 
----------
       4 
(1 row)
```

This looks like a dirty read. If I was to run the transactions serially I would not get this result. Why is this then considered SERIALIZABLE?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

For various performance and concurrency reasons, sequences are non-transactional, but atomic. In other words, they always give a distinct value to each session, but they don't reuse values, nor are they "gapless" where they return a continuous sequence of numbers.

The second transaction in your example was handed distinct sequence values for each of the rows inserted, and since that is atomic, but non-transactional, the first transaction sees the sequence's nextval increased even though the transaction isolation level is SERIALIZEABLE.

The behavior is noted at the bottom in the [Sequence Manipulation Functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-sequence.html) documentation.

Neil Conway also explains this quite well in his post [FAQ: Using Sequences in PostgreSQL](http://www.neilconway.org/docs/sequences/), including a link to a method of creating a "gapless" sequence that should behave how you had initially expected, but at the cost of some concurrency and performance.